# TastyPie: Consulting and updating fields from other models within a resource

Tags: api, tastypie

I have a Profile model with a OneToOne relationship with a User. For such Profile model I use the following class, which uses two additional fields coming directly from the User:

```
class ProfileResource(ModelResource):
    username = fields.CharField(attribute='user__username')
    email = fields.CharField(attribute='user__email')

    class Meta:
        # Base data
        queryset = Profile.objects.all()

        # Allowed methods
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'patch']

        # Security setup (FEEBLE)
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
```

Such resource works fine when consulting profiles. It retrieves the username and email perfectly, and is capable of filtering and ordering by such parameters.
However, I cannot manage to update such fields on the User model in a, say, elegant fashion. All I have come up with is this:

```
    def obj_update(self, bundle, skip_errors=False, **kwargs):
        bundle = super().obj_update(bundle, skip_errors=skip_errors, **kwargs)
        if 'username' in bundle.data: bundle.obj.user.username = bundle.data['username']
        if 'email' in bundle.data: bundle.obj.user.email = bundle.data['email']
        bundle.obj.user.save()
        return bundle
```

Which works fine but doesn't seem the best of solutions.

Does anybody know a better way to work out this kind of field-only relationship between a resource and a related model?